# How to switch CUDA version after installing two different version of CUDA?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda

I already had CUDA V9.0 but now i installed CUDA V10.0 with cudnn 7.3.I have upgraded my tensorflow-gpu version to 1.13.1.But when i imported tensorflow i got the following error.When i searched the version of CUDA in cmd the version was still v9.0.When i checked the environment variable both CUDA v9.0 and 10.0 was there.So how do i need to switch CUDA vrersion to 10.0

**CUDA version:-**

```
C:\Users\Gokul Adethya>nvcc --version nvcc
: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:32_Central_Daylight_Time_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176

Error:-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Gokul Adethya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to delete link to the old version:

```
cd /usr/local
sudo rm -rf cuda
```

Use this to build new link:

```
sudo ln -snf /usr/local/cuda-8.0 /usr/local/cuda
```